# Taking an action prior to ondragstart event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a drag/drop function for an application.  As you can see below, we have a grid with several squares that are draggable.  Also, notice the popup window that you see when hovering over a square.

[image: 1]]

The problem is when you start the drag event, a ghost of the square is created, but it also includes the popup window.  This is what I need to get rid of prior to the drag event starting.

[image]

Is there a way to capture an event right before the ghost image is created, so I can dismiss the popup first?

Comment: Can you provide a working example? By any change that popup-window is a sub-element of the red-box? If so - once you start drag you can remove that "copy" of the popup-window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with this...

```
$('.booked').on('dragstart', function (event) {
    self.funcs.hideWindow();
}
```